# Web Api Post ActionResult not Returning object

Tags: c#, .net-core

I can do the `[HttpGet]` and `[HttpGet("{id}")]` requests fine. But when I do `[HttpPost]`, I'm running into problems. I'm using postman to validate the http requests. I haven't setup a database yet, and am just using an api with models for now. Here is the code structure...

**controller.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using CoreStudyApi.OutgoingObjects;
using CoreStudyApi.Api;
using CoreStudyApi.IncomingObjects;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;

namespace CoreStudyApi.Controllers
{
    [Route("people")]
    [ApiController]
    [Produces("application/json")]
    public class PeopleController : Controller
    {
        private People_API P_API = new People_API();

        [HttpGet]
        public IActionResult Get()
        {
            var Result = P_API.GetPeople().ToList(); // Cannot pass Dictionary over httprequest, must convert to list or string.
            //var Result = "test";
            /*var Result = new List<string>()
            {
                "one",
                "two",
                "three"
            };*/
            return Ok(Result);
        }

        [HttpGet("{id}")]
        [ProducesResponseType(StatusCodes.Status200OK)]
        [ProducesResponseType(StatusCodes.Status404NotFound)]
        public IActionResult Get(int Id)
        {
            try
            {
                var Result = P_API.GetPersonNameById(Id);
                return Ok(Result);
            } catch(Exception e)
            {
                return NotFound(e.Message);
                // return NotFound("User not found");
                // return NotFound();
            }

        }

        [HttpPost]
        [ProducesResponseType(StatusCodes.Status201Created)]
        [ProducesResponseType(StatusCodes.Status400BadRequest)]
        public ActionResult<Person> Post([FromBody] PersonName NameObject)
        {
            string Name = NameObject.Name;
            if(string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(Name))
            {
                return BadRequest();
            }

            Person NewPerson = P_API.AddPerson(Name);

            return CreatedAtAction("Created", new { id = NewPerson.Id, name = NewPerson.Name }, NewPerson);
        }
    }
}
```

I can see the Person object was created successfully (using visual studio debugger) and has the values of an Id to 6 and a Name to "scrappy", but the problem hits when I try to do the return.

**People_API.cs**

```
using CoreStudyApi.OutgoingObjects;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using CoreStudyApi.Models;

namespace CoreStudyApi.Api
{
    public class People_API
    {
        // Variables
        private People P_Model = new People();

        // Helper Functions
        private int GetNextUnusedPeopleId()
        {
            for(int NewId = 1; NewId < P_Model.PeopleRecords.Count(); NewId++)
            {
                if (!P_Model.PeopleRecords.ContainsKey(NewId))
                {
                    return NewId;
                }
            }
            return P_Model.PeopleRecords.Count() + 1;
        }
        // Private Functions
        private Dictionary<int, string> GetPeopleFromData()
        {
            return P_Model.PeopleRecords;
        }
        private string GetPersonNameByIdFromData(int Id)
        {
            if (!P_Model.PeopleRecords.ContainsKey(Id))
            {
                return "Not Found";
            }
            return P_Model.PeopleRecords[Id];
        }
        private Person AddPersonToData(string Name)
        {
            // Get the next available Id
            int NewId = GetNextUnusedPeopleId();
            // Add the new person to the data
            P_Model.PeopleRecords.Add(NewId, Name);
            // Check to see if the new person was added and store as an object
            Person NewPerson = new Person(NewId, P_Model.PeopleRecords[NewId]);
            // Return the person added in the form of a person object
            return NewPerson;
        }
        // Public Functions
        public Dictionary<int, string> GetPeople()
        {
            return GetPeopleFromData();
        }
        public string GetPersonNameById(int Id)
        {
            return GetPersonNameByIdFromData(Id);
        }
        public Person AddPerson(string Name)
        {
            return AddPersonToData(Name);
        }
    }
}
```

**PersonName.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace CoreStudyApi.IncomingObjects
{
    public class PersonName
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }
}
```

**People.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace CoreStudyApi.Models
{
    public class People
    {
        public Dictionary<int, string> PeopleRecords = new Dictionary<int, string>()
        {
            { 1, "shaggy" },
            { 2, "fred" },
            { 3, "velma" },
            { 4, "daphne" },
            { 5, "scooby" }
        };
    }
}
```

**Person.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace CoreStudyApi.OutgoingObjects
{
    public class Person
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public string Name { get; set; }

        // Constructor
        public Person(int Id, string Name)
        {
            this.Id = Id;
            this.Name = Name;
        }
    }
}
```

The problem code snippet...

```
[HttpPost]
[ProducesResponseType(StatusCodes.Status201Created)]
[ProducesResponseType(StatusCodes.Status400BadRequest)]
public ActionResult<Person> Post([FromBody] PersonName NameObject)
{
    string Name = NameObject.Name;
    if(string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(Name))
    {
        return BadRequest();
    }
     Person NewPerson = P_API.AddPerson(Name); // Debugger confirms object was created successfully
     // Fails to return here
     return CreatedAtAction("Created", new { id = NewPerson.Id, name = NewPerson.Name }, NewPerson);
}
```

Receives the following with postman:
[image]

**Updated Per Request:**

Postman Output

```
System.InvalidOperationException: No route matches the supplied values.
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.CreatedAtActionResult.OnFormatting(ActionContext context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ObjectResultExecutor.ExecuteAsyncCore(ActionContext context, ObjectResult result, Type objectType, Object value)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ObjectResultExecutor.ExecuteAsync(ActionContext context, ObjectResult result)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ObjectResult.ExecuteResultAsync(ActionContext context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.InvokeResultAsync(IActionResult result)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.ResultNext[TFilter,TFilterAsync](State& next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.InvokeNextResultFilterAsync[TFilter,TFilterAsync]()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.Rethrow(ResultExecutedContextSealed context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.ResultNext[TFilter,TFilterAsync](State& next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.InvokeResultFilters()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeFilterPipelineAsync>g__Awaited|19_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeAsync>g__Awaited|17_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task task, IDisposable scope)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointMiddleware.<Invoke>g__AwaitRequestTask|6_0(Endpoint endpoint, Task requestTask, ILogger logger)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.AuthorizationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)

HEADERS
=======
Accept: */*
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Cache-Control: no-cache
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 22
Content-Type: application/json
Host: localhost:44325
User-Agent: PostmanRuntime/7.21.0
Postman-Token: 33b94ca5-5a81-451c-9221-380d27a17536
```

Comment: Shouldn't your request url be `../People/Post` because your controller action named `Post`?

Comment: @vendettamit As long as the method has the [HttpPost] attribute w/o another [Route] defining attribute it should be able to direct to it just based on the action

Comment: could you try specifying application/json explicitly in Accept header (I do not see this in the screenshot that you pasted)  Accept: application/json, text/javascript, */*;

Comment: Your `CreatedAtAction("Created", new { id = NewPerson.Id, name = NewPerson.Name }, NewPerson);` constructs the url to GET the created resource. Does that route exist and is your Postman redirecting to that URL?

Comment: @sam I already have it in the header on postman Content-Type application/json

Comment: @Jason The route exists, otherwise I would get a 405 response. Using postman to `POST` sends a post request for the action http request. So the url should be fine (works fine when I do it this way with nodejs/express).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks to me like the issue you are experiencing occurs **after** the POST has executed.

Here is the signature for the method you use to return, according to the documentation:

```
[Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.NonAction]
public virtual Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.CreatedAtActionResult CreatedAtAction (string actionName, object routeValues, object value);
```

The method creates an instance of type `CreatedAtActionResult` which returns a response with a `Location` header constructed using the parameters you pass. For 201 responses, this header represents the URL to the newly created resource (where you can find it).

I don't see an Action method called `Created` in your code. I think it's trying to construct the Url using `"created"` and `new { id = NewPerson.Id, name = NewPerson.Name }` and it can't find a matching route, so it fails.

Change the return line to this:

```
return CreatedAtAction("Get", new { id = NewPerson.Id }, NewPerson);
```

This should result in a route that matches the existing method `public IActionResult Get(int Id)`.

Comment: Maybe I don't fully understand the documentation which suggests to use `nameof(GetById)`. But I couldn't figure out where to pull that from so I just replaced it with a string `"created"`. I'm still not sure what the solution here is.

Comment: @FiddleFreak: The `nameof(GetById)` call would return a string representing the name of a method which in code is called `GetById`. It's syntactic sugar meant to allow you to use a reference to the method name so that if you ever rename the method, you don't have to go find places where you used its name. The code sample you were looking at must have a method somewhere in the controller called `GetById`. Therefore, if you provide `"created"`, then your controller must have a method with that name and it must take the arguments you provide on the second parameter to the call.

Comment: @FiddleFreak: I udpated my answer. Please take another look.

Comment: https://youtu.be/cHWnzFlmIKM?t=2604 This is where I was reading from. I also looked at the documentation here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/first-web-api?view=aspnetcore-3.0&tabs=visual-studio. But nowhere is `nameof(GetTodoItem)` defined.

Comment: Awesome update. I have no idea why "Get" is working. But it definitely works!

Comment: @FiddleFreak: If you want to use `nameof`, you would need to do this: `nameof(Get)`. This is because the `Get` method exists in your controller.

Comment: Ah okay, I think I am beginning to understand. So the psudo code of `CreatedAtAction(nameof(UseMethodInController), use new object to confirm id exists by calling method, id comes from this object)`... at least that is my guess. If the method returns the found created entry, then 201 is confirmed...

Comment: @FiddleFreak Close. The `CreatedAtActionResult` class does two things: It returns an HTTP status of `201` and it sets a `Location` header that tells the consumer where they can find this newly created item. In other words, where the new item is `CreatedAt` (hence the name). To do this, it must construct the URL and it's using internal classes that validate the route in the process. Since it couldn't find a `created` method in your controller, it threw an error.

Answer (score 1):

Return the Person object directly instead of returning CreatedAtAction.

```
    [HttpPost]
    [ProducesResponseType(StatusCodes.Status201Created)]
    [ProducesResponseType(StatusCodes.Status400BadRequest)]
    public ActionResult<Person> Post([FromBody] PersonName NameObject)
    {
        string Name = NameObject.Name;
        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(Name))
        {
            return BadRequest();
        }
        Person NewPerson = P_API.AddPerson(Name); // Debugger confirms object was created successfully
                                                  // Fails to return here
        return NewPerson; //  CreatedAtAction("Created", new { id = NewPerson.Id, name = NewPerson.Name }, NewPerson);
    }
```

Comment: This works as well, but the return action status is 200, not 201.

Comment: I would expect from ActionResult<T> then the return type would be T if it was a good request.  For a CreatedAtAction I would return IActionResult .  ActionResult<T> lets you return the object directly rather than redirecting the client to another endpoint to get it.  At a glance it would seem like you were not interested in doing this since you did not initially satisfy the requirement of creating the endpoint that returns the object or wiring it up properly.  In Swagger UI or some code generated clients returning T might be cleaner. Just another approach.